# How to use double Selectors with priorities in provider package?

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, provider, state-management

I have this widget that listens to a provider. It won't change until the `p1.boolanalyt1` increment. It now works fine. My problem is that the data changes also but I want to do `p1.boolanalyt1` as the first priority, then we can change data like if the data changed but the `p1.boolanalyt1` didn't increment we don't have to rebuild my question is how to do that (i did try to make two selectors one inside one but it didn't work).

```
Selector<DataProvider, int>(
        selector: (p0, p1) => p1.boolanalyt1,
        builder: (context, value, child) => ItemFilter(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            data: data
                .where((student) => seen.add(student.analytNiv1))
                .toList()
                .map((e) => Checkbox_Item(item: e.analytNiv1 ?? "VIDE"))
                .toList(),
            title: "analyt_niv1",
        ),
),
```

I tried to use Selector under a Selector but it didn't work

Comment: Please edit your question following [ask]. For instance, this part is unclear to me: "p1.boolanalyt1 didn't increment we don't have to rebuild my question is how to do that"

Comment: Also, try to add a minimal reproducible example